# How to correctly print all elements of an Array of type struct in C?

Tags: c, arrays, struct, printf

I have a struct:

```
typedef enum
{
    Cat = 1,
    Dog,
    GuineaPig,
    Parrot,
} SPECIES;

#define MaxNameLength 25
#define MaxNrAnimals 20

typedef struct
{
    char    Name[MaxNameLength];
    SPECIES Species;
    int     Age;
} ANIMAL;
```

I attempted to print only the Name string using:

```
ANIMAL animals[MaxNrAnimals];
for (int j = 0; j < sizeof(animals) / sizeof(animals[0]); j++) {
    printf("%c", animals[j].Name);
}
```

This returns:

> @dê¼╨⌠<`ä¿╠≡8\Çñ╚∞

regardless of whether or not the array "animals" is populated or not.
How would I go about correctly printing out every existing member of the array's Name?

Comment: `printf("%s\n", animals[j].Name);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `%c` format specifier is used to print a *single* character; for character *strings*, you should use the `%s` format. Also, you may want to consider adding a newline afteer each name. The following changes will do the trick:

```c
ANIMAL animals[MaxNrAnimals];
for (int j = 0; j < sizeof(animals) / sizeof(animals[0]); j++) {
//  printf("%c", animals[j].Name);
    printf("%s\n", animals[j].Name);
}
```

Note: In order for the `%s` format to work, each `Name` field should be a [`nul`-terminated string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string).

Answer (score 2):

```
ANIMAL animals[MaxNrAnimals];
for (int j = 0; j <MaxNrAnimals ; j++) {
printf("%s\n", animals[j].Name);
     }
```

try this

Answer (score 2):

Other answers are quite right in solving your problem.  I wanted to add a bit of backstory.

A C character string is the address of a contiguous sequence in memory of bytes containing character values - ie a `char*` .  The reason your output contains bizarre characters is because you told `printf` to treat the memory address pointing at the animal's name as a single character.

If we write code like this,

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  char *str = "blah blah blah";
  printf("%c\n", str);
}
```

A sane compile will warn you that you're. coercing your address into an inappropriate type:

```
$ gcc -o ct t.c
t.c:5:18: warning: format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type
      'char *' [-Wformat]
  printf("%c\n", str);
          ~~     ^~~
          %s
1 warning generated.
```

You should expect problems with any code you write that throws warnings on compilation.  The code may still finish compiling, but that doesn't mean it will work correctly.   Fix all compiler warnings immediately - C is a tricky language and if you ignore compiler warnings you will likely get unintended behavior, very possibly in seemingly unrelated parts of the code.

In my case I end up with something like this, because the first byte of the string address is not a valid printable character sequence:

```
$ ./ct
�
```

Examining the output in hexidecimal helps us see the `\n` (ascii value `0a` in my environment, aka "newlline", aka "linefeed" in ascii).  Immediately proceeding it is the hex value of the value of the '%c' output - `0xa2`.  Since this isn't in the standard 7 bit ascii table, and my terminal is set to unicode, this character is not valid and printable, thus the `�` character being displayed.

```
$ ./ct | hexdump
0000000 a2 0a
0000002
```

If we change the `%c` to a `%s`, we no longer get a compiler warning, and the code works normally.

```
$ cat t.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  char *str = "blah blah blah";
  printf("%s\n", str);
}

$ gcc -o ct t.c
[ no output ]

$ ./ct
blah blah blah

$ ./ct | hexdump
0000000 62 6c 61 68 20 62 6c 61 68 20 62 6c 61 68 0a
000000f
```

I included the hexdump in case you wanted to see how my string `blah blah blah\n` showed up byte-wise.